# Is DEET (as in the mosquito repellent), a substituted phenethylamine?

Tags: biochemistry, nomenclature, organic-chemistry

Am I correct to say that N,N-diethyl-meta-toluamide (DEET) is a part of the phenethylamine class? It's structure meets the requirements to be a phenythylamine, however, I was not able to find anywhere on the internet that it is part of the phenethylamine class.

Comment: Do you mean [phenethylamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenethylamine)? That's the only thing google turn's up. If so, they don't seem to be related (1 less carbon between ring and N, carboxylic-bound N versus amine N)

Comment: @Nicolai Sorry I usually type in Word which autocorrects me, but you are correct on the first part. But I'm confused on your second point. How come it passes the requirements to be a substituted phenethylamine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substituted_phenethylamine)?

Comment: Selegiline is a good example of what I mean, it has a carbon bound N but is part of the PEA class. Why is this then...

Comment: Also, technically DEET has a NH group because groups share atoms with the linked group, so writing N-CH3 is the same as writing NH-CH2. There is no difference, unless it crosses over 1 link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology, but is a question about the chemical structure of a proprietary product.

Answer (score 3):

While I feel like this might be a better question for the chemistry SE, lets take a look at the molecular structures:

The basic structure of a phenethylamine (left, modified from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substituted_phenethylamine)) versus DEET (right, modified from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEET)):

[image]

The important chemical differences are:

1. DEET only has a C-alpha between the nitrogen and the ring, whereas phenethylamines have a C-alpha and a C-beta (see red annotation)
2. DEET has a carboxylic functional group (an [amide bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide_bond)), whereas phenethylamines have an [amino group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amine) (see green boxes)

Taken together these differences mean that DEET is not a phenethylamine.

Comment: So are you saying that 1-phenethylamine is not part of the phenethylamine class?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Phenylethylamine

Comment: Note, I am not talking about b-phenethylamine which is the one you pointed out

Comment: @kirill2485 At least based on the different carbon chains of these molecules I wouldn't group them together. I'm not a chemist however, so if you want to now how they categorise this, ask the question at chemistry.SE

Comment: I agree with @Nicolai I can't see any reason it would make sense to consider DEET a phenethylamine; it doesn't have an "ethylamine" on it anywhere: that would be 2 carbons followed by a nitrogen. It's an N-substituted amide group (one carbon) on a toluene.